# Expo (react native) fade out splash screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo

Currently Expo’s splash screen hides as soon as the app is loaded, but I want it to gradually fade out.

How can this be achieved?

Expo’s splash screen docs: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/splash-screens.html

Answer (score 0):

I found that expo is too limiting with anything more than a very basic app. So I just switched to normal react native and installed a splash screen plugin. Now I have nice fade out of a splashcreen.